# How to Covert RGB Value To Color object?

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors, rgb

i get some Color Value like #FF6100. 
now i was need Covert #FF6100 to a Color Object in my Windows phone Application?
is There have any suggestion?
TX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do the job for you:

```
public static Color GetColorFromHexString(string s)
{

    byte a = System.Convert.ToByte("FF", 16);//Alpha should be 255
    byte r = System.Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(0, 2), 16);
    byte g = System.Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(2, 2), 16);
    byte b = System.Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(4, 2), 16);
    return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
}
```

HTH,
Rupert.